# jquery cannot find id when nested, but finds it when not nested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a piece of HTML like this:

```
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="popup">
      <h1> Webpage chatter </h1>
      <button id="signOut">Sign Out</button>
      <div id="welcome-section">
        <div id="invalid-error-msg" class="invalid-input-text">
        </div>
      </div>
  ...
```

And a jquery script that modifies the id=invalid-error-msg element:

```
$("#invalid-error-msg").append("<p>Too short. Display name must be 6 or more characters.</p>");
```

The jquery does not find the invalid-error-msg id, but if I un-nest that div like below, it finds it and modifies it with no problem.

```
  <body>
    <!-- show a text box, a list of persons in chat, chat box, header title -->
    <div id="main" class="popup">
      <h1> Webpage chatter </h1>
      <button id="signOut">Sign Out</button>
      <div id="welcome-section">
      </div>
      <div id="invalid-error-msg" class="invalid-input-text">
      </div>
```

Why is this happening? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Could CSS that applies to #welcome-section be hiding it or its children?

Comment: @oflahero and that would matter how?

Comment: When you do a `console.log($("#invalid-error-msg"))`, what do you get in both cases?

Comment: It wouldn't matter if you appended a hundred <h1> headers to #invalid-error-msg Anurag, if it had an ancestor that was display: none;, say.

Comment: Are you sure it's not finding it? Check the DOM inspector to see if it's working.

Comment: My guess is that you have CSS along the lines of '#welcome-section #invalid-error-msg.invalid-input.text { display: none; } or visibility: hidden; somewhere.

Comment: @oflahero I'm well aware of how elements are hidden in html, thank you. My question was more addressing the fact that OP says the selector does not find the element with given id. Maybe its poor choice of wording from their side.

Comment: Sorry Anurag, but there's no other way to answer a 'and that would matter how?'

Given that I'm not seeing any kind of $("#invalid-error-msg").length check above, I'm reckoning it's pretty likely that OP's just referring to the end result :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava console.log($("invalid-error-msg").length) gives 0 for first case, 1 for second case.

Comment: I found the error, I was overwriting the contents of "welcome-section" by calling .html() earlier. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery always finds an element as long as it exists in the rendered DOM. So you might want to check id="welcome-section" (which is the wrapper/parent) CSS. It must've been hidden or displayed none.